# how to use radio buttons in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Creating a Registration page, I need to get the following data from user.

- First Name
- Last Name
- Username
- Email
- Password
- Date of Birth
- **Gender**
- **User Role**

For the last two parameters, I am unable to find how to use radio buttons in Xamarin.Forms. Following is my code for the Registration Page.

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="#30af91" Padding="60">


<Entry Text="{Binding FirstName}" Placeholder="First Name"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding LastName}" Placeholder="Last Name"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding UserName}" Placeholder="Last Name"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email" />
<Entry Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding ConfirmPassword}" Placeholder="Confirm Password" IsPassword="True"/>
<DatePicker MinimumDate="1/1/1948" MaximumDate="12/31/2007"/>


<!--Radio buttons for Gender
    1. Male   2.Female-->

<!--Radio Buttons for UserRole
    1. Admin  2.Participant-->

<Button Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}" Text="Register"/>
<Label Text="{Binding Message}" />


</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xamarin forms does not provide Radio Button.

You can either use

**1)[Switch](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Switch/)**

**2)[Picker](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/)**

or any other component to fulfill your requirement

**UPDATE**

The xamarin forms update version 4.6 has introduced the Radio button control, Here is the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton)

Comment: "Xamarin.Forms 4.6 introduced a new RadioButton control. You can find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton" -Thanks, @jfmg

Answer (score 6):

I think there is a simpler solution that is fairly easy and requires no libraries. Really a a radio group is just a fancy ListView. You would just need to create a viewModel for each radio button that has a IsSelected flag and switch between 2 images. I had a need to allow a user to select how long a token persisted:

**XAML**

```
<ListView
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Durations}"
    ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDuration}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image
                        HeightRequest="18"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}"
                        Source="radioButtonChecked.png"
                        WidthRequest="18"/>
                    <Image
                        HeightRequest="18"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsUnselected}"
                        Source="radioButtonUnchecked.png"
                        WidthRequest="18"/>
                    <Label
                        Margin="8,0,0,0"
                        Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

*We create a listview in our content page and listen for the ItemSelected event. Each list item is a horizontal stack panel where we flip between two images depending on the selected state*

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    LoginPageViewModel LoginPageViewModel { get; }

    public LoginTwoFactorFrequencyPage ()
    {
        BindingContext = LoginPageViewModel = new LoginPageViewModel();

        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginPageViewModel.UpdateSelected(e.SelectedItem as PersistenceDuration);
    }
}
```

- The page's code behind instantiates a view model and calls an UpdateSelected method with the newly selected item on the page's view model*

**RadioButton ViewModel**

The view model for each radio button:

```
public class PersistenceDuration : ViewModelBase
{
    bool isSelected;

    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public TwoFactorTokenPersistenceDuration Duration { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => isSelected;
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("IsUnselected");
        }
    }
    public bool IsUnselected => !IsSelected;

    public PersistenceDuration(string caption, TwoFactorTokenPersistenceDuration duration)
    {
        Caption = caption;
        Duration = duration;
        IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

*The radio button view model holds selection info and the caption. We make sure to fire OnPropertyChanged whenever the selected state changes*

**Page ViewModel**

```
public class LoginPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    PersistenceDuration duration;
    PersistenceDuration selectedDuration;

    public ObservableCollection<PersistenceDuration> Durations { get; }
    public PersistenceDuration SelectedDuration
    {
        get => selectedDuration;
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                duration = value;
                UpdateSelected(duration);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public LoginTwoFactorFrequencyViewModel()
    {
        Durations = new ObservableCollection<PersistenceDuration>(
            new List<PersistenceDuration>()
            {
                new PersistenceDuration(AppResources.Save_code__forever, TwoFactorTokenPersistenceDuration.Forever),
                new PersistenceDuration(AppResources.ChatRequireEvery30Days, TwoFactorTokenPersistenceDuration.ThirtyDays),
                new PersistenceDuration(AppResources.ChatRequireEveryLogin, TwoFactorTokenPersistenceDuration.None),
            });
    }

    public void UpdateSelected(PersistenceDuration persistenceDuration)
    {
        foreach (var item in Durations)
            item.IsSelected = persistenceDuration == item;
    }
}
```

*In the page view model we create a list of radio button view models that the XAML binds to. When we UpdateSelected() all the IsSelected states are updated which trigger binding updates which flip the image.*

You will still need to do something about the highlight when someone selects an item, but that is easy enough to find on the internet :)

Comment: I edited this to use a second variable to hold the reference and never set the actual selected item. This allows you to avoid the ListView item from getting selected and adding a system color to the background. You will still get hover and click highlights however. There is no easy way to set list item selected color cross-platform (hopefully the xamarin guys fix this soon)

Answer (score 3):

You can use XLabs plugin from manage NuGets package. After installing you can use like this:

In Xaml:

```
controls:BindableRadioGroup x:Name="Radiobtn"
```

In C#:

```
string[] gender = {"MAlE","FEMALE"}
Radiobtn.Add(gender)
```

Refer Link
https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/samples/XLabs.Samples/XLabs.Samples/Pages/Controls

Comment: NOTE: XLabs is no longer maintained. Won't even build in latest Xamarin Forms, IIRC. Still, it is useful collection of code to show you techniques for using Xamarin Forms. Rather than using NuGet package, download from github link above.  Extract parts of code you are interested in. Modify to work in current version of Xamarin Forms.

Comment: FYI, I just took a look at what XLabs did for Radio buttons. Its all done with custom renderers. Still looking for a good example that shows what could be done in X-Forms without using custom renderers. Would like to only use custom renderers after determining that it is necessary to do so. So far, I don't think radio buttons are complex enough to require custom rendering. (X-Labs was done a couple of years ago, when X-Forms was more limited.)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the radio button effect without a package. Use Labels with text unicode circle `\u26AA` or `\u25CB`. Attach a tab gesture recognizer to each label.

When tapped, change the text of the selected button to unicode circle bullet `\u29BF` and change the text of the other button(s) back to unicode circle `\u26AA`.

Test on your preferred platforms as each platform may display somewhat differently. You may need to adjust the font size as you change the text.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.Forms 4.6 introduced a new `RadioButton` control. You can find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton

Answer (score 1):

You can use image as a radio button. When tou you click on it, it can change. It is not a good way to do it though.
This is xaml code:

```
<Image  Scale="0.7"  HorizontalOptions="Start" x:Name="radioButton" Source="unRadioBtn.png">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="radioButton_Clicked"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
```

And this is .cs:

```
 private void radioButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton.Source = "radioBtn.png";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want real radiobuttons you can xlabs their package (https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/RadioButton)

Personally I'd just use a picker, Xlabs package hasn't been updated in a while so their might be some bugs in the radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [switch component](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Switch/). Also you can see the implementation for a checkbox component from the [XLabs project](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/2.2.0/samples/XLabs.Samples/XLabs.Samples/Pages/Controls/CheckBoxPage.xaml) which is now discontinued, get the code and modify it as you need.

Hint: You're gonna need the custom renderers per platform for it to work .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Picker`
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/
Actually it is the best alternative to `RadionButton` On **Xamarin.forms**

Comment: Unfortunately, picker is very limited re styling control. Have to write custom renderer per platform, to do anything interesting with it.

Answer (score 0):

XLabs RadioButton and BindableRadioGroup work well: [XLabs RadioButton for Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/RadioButton)

Here's a simple Yes/No radio using the BindableRadioGroup:

```
var answers = new List<string>();
answers.Add("Yes");
answers.Add("No");

var RadioGroup = new XLabs.Forms.Controls.BindableRadioGroup()
{
  ItemsSource = answers, 
  Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Forms now provides a Radio Button control.

See docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton

As of XF 4.8 this is still experimental and I've not yet used this feature so can't comment on its stability.