# How can I implement a click to select using a ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML that displays 6 TextCells which can show a check mark or not. They also so as enabled or not enabled:

```
<TableSection Title="Front Side" x:Name="cfsSection">
   <local:CustomTextCell Text="{Binding [0].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [0].IsSelected}" IsEnabled="{Binding [0].IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter} } "Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell Text="{Binding [1].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [1].IsSelected}" IsEnabled="{Binding [1].IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter} } "Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell Text="{Binding [2].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [2].IsSelected}" IsEnabled="{Binding [2].IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter} } "Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell Text="{Binding [3].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [3].IsSelected}" IsEnabled="{Binding [3].IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter} } "Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell Text="{Binding [4].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [4].IsSelected}" IsEnabled="{Binding [4].IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter} } "Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell Text="{Binding [5].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [5].IsSelected}" IsEnabled="{Binding [5].IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter} } "Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
</TableSection>
```

The code behind is I think fairly simple. It declares an array of SSVViewModel and the binding causes the text to display:

```
    SSVViewModel[] CFS = new[] {
        new SSVViewModel {Id = 0, Name=LANG.English.Text(), IsSelected = false},
        new SSVViewModel {Id = 1, Name=LANG.Romaji.Text(), IsSelected = false},
        new SSVViewModel {Id = 2, Name=LANG.Kana.Text(), IsSelected = false},
        new SSVViewModel {Id = 3, Name=LANG.Kanji.Text(), IsSelected = false},
        new SSVViewModel {Id = 4, Name=LANG.KanjiKana.Text(), IsSelected = false},
        new SSVViewModel {Id = 5, Name=LANG.KanaKanji.Text(), IsSelected = false},
    };
```

When a cell is clicked this function is called:

```
void cfsSelectValue(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        var cell = sender as TextCell;
        if (cell == null)
            return;

        var selected = cell.Text;

        foreach (var setting in CFS)
            setting.IsSelected = false;

        foreach (var setting in CFS)
            if (setting.Name == selected)
                setting.IsSelected = true;

 }
```

However when clicking on either of the first two cells both show as checked.  All other cell clicks work fine. In another part of my code I use a similar construct and it's the last two cells that do not work.

**Note that the IsEnabled works but not the IsChecked**

Can anyone see why a click on the first two cells could possibly give any problem. I have been through this with the debugger many time but I still cannot see what might be wrong. Surely the code that sets the IsSelected to false should cause all except the one cell to show as checked.

Note that when debugging this line: setting.IsSelected = false; and this line:  setting.IsSelected = true; then everything appears as it should as the correct cell has it's IsSelected set to true and the others to false.  It's just when I look at the display it seems like the binding didn't work for those first two cells.

Here's the viewModel code I am using:

```
public class SSVViewModel: ObservableProperty
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private bool isSelected;

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != id)
            {
                id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != isSelected)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the CustomTextCellRenderer

```
public class CustomTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
{
    UITableViewCell _nativeCell;

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        _nativeCell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
        var formsCell = item as CustomTextCell;

        if (formsCell != null)
        {
            formsCell.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
            formsCell.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        }

        SetCheckmark(formsCell);
        SetTap(formsCell);

        return _nativeCell;
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var formsCell = sender as CustomTextCell;
        if (formsCell == null)
            return;

        if (e.PropertyName == CustomTextCell.IsCheckedProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            SetCheckmark(formsCell);
        }

        if (e.PropertyName == CustomTextCell.NoTapProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            SetTap(formsCell);
        }
    }

    private void SetCheckmark(CustomTextCell formsCell)
    {
        if (formsCell.IsChecked)
            _nativeCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
        else
            _nativeCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
    }

    private void SetTap(CustomTextCell formsCell)
    {
        if (formsCell.NoTap)
            _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        else
            _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default;
    }

}
```

**Update 1**

```
<local:CustomTextCell           Text="{Binding [0].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [0].IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue" CommandParameter="0" />
<local:CustomTextCell           Text="{Binding [1].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [1].IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue" CommandParameter="1" />
<local:CustomTextCell           Text="{Binding [2].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [2].IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue" CommandParameter="2" />
<local:CustomTextCell           Text="{Binding [3].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [3].IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue" CommandParameter="3" />
<local:CustomTextCell           Text="{Binding [4].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [4].IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue" CommandParameter="4" />
```

Since the question was written I have stopped using this for the Lang selection however it's still used in another part of the code and I tried to put in some debug points. Here's what I did:

I added this to the iOS custom renderer:

```
    private void SetCheckmark(CustomTextCell formsCell)
    {
        if (formsCell.IsChecked)
        {
            _nativeCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
            Debug.WriteLine(_nativeCell.TextLabel.Text + " checked");
        }
        else
        {
            _nativeCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
            Debug.WriteLine(_nativeCell.TextLabel.Text + " unchecked");
        }
    }
```

Here's the result when I clicked JLPT N2:

```
Category Group unchecked
Category unchecked
All Available Words unchecked
Japanese for Busy People 1 unchecked
Japanese for Busy People 2 unchecked
Japanese for Busy People 3 unchecked
JLPT Level N5 unchecked
JLPT Level N4 unchecked
JLPT Level N3 unchecked
JLPT Level N2 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N3 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N2 checked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
JLPT Level N1 unchecked
```

This was not at all what I expected.

On the screen I see that as expected N2 is disabled but there is a check mark next to N3 and N2.

Not sure if this helps but I notice the iOS renderer code used is different from similar code I have used in other places.  For example here's a different iOS renderer. Code looks very different. I realize function is different but this one has things like `cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(fullName) as CellTableViewCell;`

```
public class TextCellCustomRenderer : TextCellRenderer
{
    CellTableViewCell cell;
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var textCell = (TextCell)item;
        var fullName = item.GetType().FullName;
        cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(fullName) as CellTableViewCell;

        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new CellTableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, fullName);
        }
        else
        {
            cell.Cell.PropertyChanged -= cell.HandlePropertyChanged;
            //cell.Cell.PropertyChanged -= Current_PropertyChanged;
        }

        cell.Cell = textCell;
        textCell.PropertyChanged += cell.HandlePropertyChanged;
        cell.PropertyChanged = this.HandlePropertyChanged;
        cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        cell.TextLabel.Text = textCell.Text;
        cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = textCell.Detail;
        cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;


        switch (item.StyleId)
        {
            case "checkmark":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
                break;
            case "detail-button":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailButton;
                break;
            case "detail-disclosure-button":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
                break;
            case "disclosure":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
                break;
            case "none":
            default:
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
                break;
        }

        //UpdateBackground(cell, item);

        return cell;
    }

    void checkAccessoryVisibility() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the log statements, it looks like the unsubscribe logic for property-changed-handler is not working as expected.

With `TextCellRenderer`, we don't need to explicitly subscribe to property-changed-event as there is a base overridable method `HandlePropertyChanged` that can be re-used in this context.

Changing the renderer code to use this method ([similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45784618/7292772)) should hopefully resolve this problem:

```
public class CustomTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var nativeCell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

        if (item is CustomTextCell formsCell)
        {
            SetCheckmark(nativeCell, formsCell);
            SetTap(nativeCell, formsCell);
        }

        return nativeCell;
    }

    protected override void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.HandlePropertyChanged(sender, args);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"HandlePropertyChanged {args.PropertyName}");

        var nativeCell = sender as CellTableViewCell;
        if (nativeCell?.Element is CustomTextCell formsCell)
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == CustomTextCell.IsCheckedProperty.PropertyName)
                SetCheckmark(nativeCell, formsCell);
            else if (args.PropertyName == CustomTextCell.NoTapProperty.PropertyName)
                SetTap(nativeCell, formsCell);
        }
    }

    void SetCheckmark(UITableViewCell nativeCell, CustomTextCell formsCell)
    {
        if (formsCell.IsChecked)
            nativeCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
        else
            nativeCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
    }

    void SetTap(UITableViewCell nativeCell, CustomTextCell formsCell)
    {
        if (formsCell.NoTap)
            _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        else
            _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try your changes and report back.

Comment: Okay, I just tried now with the simulator and it seems to be working okay.  I will do some more tests and update / award the bounty if all is good.  Thanks for your very quick help on this. Btw if this works out okay I might open another question to ask for recommendations on the other custom renderer.  Thanks again

Comment: Quick question.  Do you think it's necessary to do this code: var fullName = item.GetType().FullName;
        cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(fullName) as CellTableViewCell;  I saw that in another answer before.  Also just letting you know, I opened up a similar question about renderers just now.  Thanks

Comment: Frankly, I am not exactly sure how `DequeueReusableCell` works in context of property-changed handling. I will have to do some research and update you.

Answer (score 5):

I could not find the error causing that behaviour so here are my thoughts on this:

The behaviour you are describing sounds more like a `RadioButton`. [Since there are none in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143634/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-xamarin-forms) you could create your own, use a package or get a workaround.

Most easy workaround would be in your `cfsSelectValue`.

You could search the visual tree for all elements of  `local:CustomTextCells` and set `IsSelected` to false for each `TextCell` that is **not** the one passed as the `sender`.

---

**How I would do it:**

Things to try out:

For your ViewModels use an [ObservableCollection](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%601/) rather than an `Array`

```
private ObservableCollection<SSVViewModel> viewModels = new ObservableCollection<SSVViewModel>()
{
    new SSVViewModel {Id = 0, Name=LANG.English.Text()},
    new SSVViewModel {Id = 1, Name=LANG.Romaji.Text()},
    new SSVViewModel {Id = 2, Name=LANG.Kana.Text()},
    new SSVViewModel {Id = 3, Name=LANG.Kanji.Text()},
    new SSVViewModel {Id = 4, Name=LANG.KanjiKana.Text()},
    new SSVViewModel {Id = 5, Name=LANG.KanaKanji.Text()},
};
```

Derive your ViewModel from `INotifyPropertyChanged` rather than `ObservableProperty`

```
public class SSVViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private bool isSelected = false; //Set the default here

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != id)
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != isSelected)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Change your `cfsSelectValue` to this:

```
public void cfsSelectValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //GetCurrentCell
    CustomTextCell cell = sender as CustomTextCell;
    if (cell == null)
    {
        return;
    }            

    foreach (SSVViewModel viewModel in CFS)
    {
        /*
        Since there is no Tag Property we gotta use something different
        you could use `CommandParameter` since it is of type object

        */
        if (viewModel.Name == cell.Text && viewModel.Id == int.Parse(cell.CommandParameter.ToString()))
        {
            viewModel.IsSelected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            viewModel.IsSelected = false;
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look at the code. I have been trying to work this out for two hours now and still no luck.  I tried setting everything to be false in the hope that would work.  I looked and saw that only one thing was being set to true.  Makes no sense to me at all :-(

Comment: I'm a little confused about your `TableSection` - does it have an `ItemsSource` ?

Comment: cfsSection.BindingContext = CFS;

Comment: Just to test something out I tried removing one of those first cells so there were only five cells left.  Still I get the case where clicking on either of the first two causes both to be shown as selected.

Comment: And the `Text` is different in each of them ?

Comment: Yes it is.  Just an update.  I have another person here who tried the same code and on their phone the two middle cells seem to be connected to each other.

Comment: @Alan2 I recommend trying my code above. This may ensure no cell could get triggered twice.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that now

Comment: Did you add a cell.name and cell.tag.  I have errors saying those are not found.

Comment: I guess your `CustomTextCell` has those properties ? - My bad `Name` should be `Text` and you got to add `Tag` to your XAML  definition

Comment: I will add the code for the CustomTextCell to the question.  It inherits from TextCell but my XAML doesn't specify a name or tag

Comment: I tried with your latest edit and it's telling me CommandParameter is null and so gives an exception.

Comment: did you set in in xaml ? like `<local:CustomTextCell Text="{Binding [0].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [0].IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue" CommandParameter="0"/>` ?

Comment: I just tried that now.  The result is the first two cells select together and the remaining 3 cells don't select at all.  This is getting to be a big mystery :-(

Comment: Yes I did but didn't do those first three suggestions that you made as I am not sure how to do them.  I'll post the latest XAML at the end of the question so you can see what I changed.

Comment: Correction to my last comment.  The first two select together and the other three work okay.  So same result as before.

Comment: As an update. I see the original code works in the simulator but not on the phone. I am using all the latest stable release of Xamarin code etc.

Comment: Further update.  The code works when it's the only thing on the page.  As I add more elements into the page in different table sections in then it starts to not work for the first two rows. I moved all of the original code to another page and it works okay.

Comment: Yes very strange.  Even more strange that on another phone instead of the first two elements being "linked", it's the 2nd and 3rd. and the 1st element works as intended. I didn't yet try your solution as I'm waiting on Xcode update and looks like that will take a while.  I will update this question when I have tried your suggestion.

Comment: @Alan2 so you could fix it ?

Answer (score 5):

The code looks right to me - the only reason I would imagine this happening is in case the string comparison logic is not working as expected.

Maybe a reference based comparison might solve the issue. i.e Change your XAML to:

```xml
<TableSection Title="Front Side" x:Name="cfsSection">
   <local:CustomTextCell BindingContext="{Binding [0]}" Text="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell BindingContext="{Binding [1]}" Text="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell BindingContext="{Binding [2]}" Text="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell BindingContext="{Binding [3]}" Text="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell BindingContext="{Binding [4]}" Text="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
   <local:CustomTextCell BindingContext="{Binding [5]}" Text="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Tapped="cfsSelectValue"/>
</TableSection>
```

and tapped handler to:

```cs
void cfsSelectValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cell = sender as TextCell;
    if (cell == null)
        return;

    var selected = cell.BindingContext;

    foreach (var setting in CFS)
        setting.IsSelected = (setting == selected);

}
```

Comment: What confuses me is that it works in the simulator, works when it's the only thing on the page but doesn't work when it's on a page with other similar controls. I will try your suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: If there are other similar controls - are you making sure to have completely different instances of `SSVViewModel` to assign as `BindingContext`?

Comment: Yes I do have different instances.

Comment: I updated the question. It really seems like it's the .IsChecked that is not working correctly as when using .IsEnabled it works fine. Also added some debug output from within the renderer and it doesn't look as expected.